# Consulta permisos a usuario para vista SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, permisos, vistas

Saben si es posible en Mysql otorgar a un usuario permisos para modificar y eliminar vistas pero **solo sobre aquellas que él mismo haya creado?**
En caso de que sí, como sería?

Desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El escenario es que que tienes dos o más usuarios y no quieres que ninguno pueda crear o eliminar las vistas de otro usuario.

La [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) dice que el privilegio `create view` solo puede otorgarse a nivel global, de base de datos o de tabla.

Tomando en cuenta la limitación de la granularidad del privilegio y la necesidad presente, una posible solución es crear una base de datos para cada usuario, donde cada uno pueda crear y eliminar vistas. Cada usuario tendría acceso a crear y eliminar cualquier vista en SU base de datos, pero como cada usuario ha creado sus vistas en una base de datos diferentes, no podría tocar las vistas de otras bases de datos, a las que no tendría permiso. En la práctica, no podría tocar las vistas de otro usuario. Esta base de datos sería una especie de *sandbox* para cada usuario.

Entiendo que dichas vistas estarían probablemente tirando de tablas que son comunes a todos los usuarios, por lo que todos tendrían que saber el nombre de la base de datos donde están y calificar el nombre de las tablas en las consultas. En mi ejemplo, asumiré que dichas tablas están en la base de datos `comun`.

Digamos que tenemos los usuarios `juan` y `pedro`, podemos hacer:

```
create database usr_juan;
grant create view on usr_juan to 'juan'@'localhost';

create database usr_pedro;
grant create view on usr_pedro to 'pedro'@'localhost';
```

Cuando `juan` quiera crear una vista, puede hacerlo en su base de datos:

```
use usr_juan;

create view MiVista as 
select t1.Campo1, t2.Campo2
  from comun.Tabla1 t1
       inner join comun.Tabla2 t2 on t2.CampoLlave = t1.CampoLlaveForanea;
```

Advertencia: He escrito el código en el propio navegador, es probable que no recuerde con exactitud la sintaxis o que tenga algún otro error. Si comprendes la idea, podrás producir tu mismo el código para aplicarla o corregir el que yo he publicado si fuese necesario.

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost';
```

Si queremos asignar permisos para ciertas acciones:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP

    -> ON clientes.*
    -> TO 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost';

use usr_mary;

create view MiVista as 
select t1.Campo1, t2.Campo2
  from comun.Tabla1 t1
       inner join comun.Tabla2 t2 on t2.CampoLlave = t1.CampoLlaveForanea;
```